# Android: Why is the getView of the Custom spinner called multiple times

Tags: java, android, kotlin, spinner

I made 3 dropDown Spinners and made Spinner Adapters and did setAdapters for each Spinner. But the problem is that when I click on the dropdown Spinner item, I call from the getView of Spinner Adapters to another Spinner, but I don't know why.

```kotlin
private fun initSeriesSpinner() {
        val series = resources.getStringArray(R.array.selectedSeriesList)
        val listOfSeries = ArrayList(mutableListOf(*series))

        spinnerSeriesAdapter =
            MonkeySpinnerViewAdapter(requireContext(), 0, listOfSeries)

        binding.spinnerSeries.adapter = spinnerSeriesAdapter
    }

    private fun initTypeSpinner() {
        val types = resources.getStringArray(R.array.selectedSeriesList)
        val listOfSeries = ArrayList(mutableListOf(*types))

        with(binding) {
            spinnerType.buildCheckedSpinner(listOfSeries) { selectedPositionList, displayString ->

            }
        }
    }

    private fun initCompareSpinner() {
        val types = resources.getStringArray(R.array.testList)
        val listOfSeries = ArrayList(mutableListOf(*types))

        binding.spinnerCompare.adapter = MonkeySpinnerViewAdapter(requireContext(), 0, listOfSeries)
    }
```

```kotlin
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val binding: ItemMultiSpinnerGetviewBinding = if (convertView == null) {
            /*Log.d("TEST","check_getView")
            Log.d("TEST","position =  $position")*/
            Log.d("TESt",">  // hashCode = ${this.hashCode()}")
            ItemMultiSpinnerGetviewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false)
                .also {
                    it.root.tag = it
                }
        } else {
            convertView.tag as ItemMultiSpinnerGetviewBinding
        }

        binding.tvBeforeClickedMultiSpinner.text = dataList[position].text

        return binding.root
    }
```

below code is in getDropDownView

```kotlin
if (isDataChanged) {
    checkedListener(dataList, position)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

The way I tried to solve it was because the resource file was the same, so I made a new array object and put it in, and I thought it was because I used the same Spinner Adapter class, so I made a separate class, but it was called together.

Comment: It is called for every 'position' . So yes multiple times. You have more items in the list we assume.